# csv file content not aligned under column names in data frame when reading with pandas

Tags: pandas, csv, unicode

I loaded it as excel

```
df = pd.read_excel('GSVP_XL.xlsx', columns=['client_id', 'agreement', 'contact_type', 'contact_number', 'group_main'])
```

in the file - client_id field has no quotes around it, i put quotes - no any difference.

and this is what df looks like:

```
client_id,"agreement","contact_type","contact_number","group_main"
0                              000101501129,"1","103",+77760013505,true
1                              851223350038,"1","103",+77779261433,false
2                              970425300903,"1","103",+77071061047,true
3                              970425301179,"1","103",+77714032401,true
4                              970425350701,"1","103",+77787763621,true
```

I tried to save it as excel and pd.read_excel().
I specified column names.

```
df = pd.read_excel('GSVP_XL.xlsx', columns=['client_id', 'agreement', 'contact_type', 'contact_number', 'group_main'])
```

even when used utf-8 encoding the bug persists

```
df = pd.read_csv('GSVP.csv', encoding='UTF-8')
```

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position
>   26: invalid start byte

Comment: Can you check the encoding of your xlsx file ? Maybe it's not encoded in utf-8.
It seems also to have some extra space between 0 and 000101501129 (for the first row), maybe there's a problem with your file. You can try also to export it in a csv file (utf-8) then try your second command again.

Comment: @piratefache i could not resolve it and just downloaded the original files again

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the printout of your DataFrame.
Note that what you want as column names (`client_id,"agreement","contact_type","contact_number","group_main"`)
has been printed as a **single** string.

So it looks like all the content in the Excel file was in the first column **only**.

To check this, open your input file using Excel and take a look at them.

Another way to confirm my suspicion is `print(df.columns)`.
If you see a list with a **single** string, I'm right.

Then probably you should reformat your input file so that *client_id*,
*agreement* and so on are in **separate** columns.

Another solution is to:

- save your Excel file as a CSV file (because the spreadsheet has only a single
  column filled with data, no commas will be in the output),
- then read this file calling *read_csv* (commas contained in your content
  will then serve as CSV column separators).

And to avoid encoding errors, start from either checking the actual encoding
of your input file or changing its encoding to *UTF-8*.

Comment: thx , i need to figure out how to reformat the file content itself